# Syntax error in VBA SQL

Tags: sql-server, vba

Getting data from various text boxes on a form and doing an update to a SQL Server database. Here is the creation of the SQL:

```
Dim upDateStr As String
upDateStr = "UPDATE dbo_Master_Accounts SET dbo_Master_Accounts.FirstName = " & Chr$(34) & Me.disFirstName & Chr$(34) & ", "
upDateStr = upDateStr + "dbo_Master_Accounts.LastName = " & Chr$(34) & Me.disLastName & Chr$(34) & ", "
upDateStr = upDateStr + "dbo_Master_Accounts.Address_Line_1 = " & Chr$(34) & Me.disAddr1 & Chr$(34) & ", "
upDateStr = upDateStr + "dbo_Master_Accounts.City = " & Chr$(34) & Me.disCity & Chr$(34) & ", "
upDateStr = upDateStr + "dbo_Master_Accounts.State = " & Chr$(34) & Me.disState & Chr$(34) & ", "
upDateStr = upDateStr + "dbo_Master_Accounts.PostalCode = " & Chr$(34) & Me.disPostalCode & Chr$(34) & ", "
upDateStr = upDateStr + "dbo_Master_Accounts.Phone_Number_1 = " & Chr$(34) & Me.disHomePhone & Chr$(34) & ", "
upDateStr = upDateStr + "dbo_Master_Accounts.Phone_Number_2 = " & Chr$(34) & Me.disCellPhone & Chr$(34) & ", "
upDateStr = upDateStr + "dbo_Master_Accounts.Gender = " & Chr$(34) & Me.disGender & Chr$(34) & ", "
upDateStr = upDateStr + "dbo_Master_Accounts.Date_Of_Birth = " & Chr$(34) & Me.disDateofBirth & Chr$(34) & ", "
upDateStr = upDateStr + "dbo_Master_Accounts.Email = " & Chr$(34) & Me.disEmailAddress & Chr$(34) & ", "
upDateStr = upDateStr + "WHERE (((dbo_Master_Accounts.Master_ID) = " & Chr$(34) & Me.frmoldCardno & Chr$(34) & ""
```

Looked at query in immediate and all the data is there and it looks correct. Here is the immediate window.

```
UPDATE dbo_Master_Accounts
SET    dbo_Master_Accounts.FirstName = "John",
       dbo_Master_Accounts.LastName = "Handy",
       dbo_Master_Accounts.Address_Line_1 = "123 From",
       dbo_Master_Accounts.City = "Somewhere",
       dbo_Master_Accounts.State = "IL",
       dbo_Master_Accounts.PostalCode = "50310",
       dbo_Master_Accounts.Phone_Number_1 = "1234567890",
       dbo_Master_Accounts.Phone_Number_2 = "",
       dbo_Master_Accounts.Gender = "M",
       dbo_Master_Accounts.Date_Of_Birth = "02/14/1967",
       dbo_Master_Accounts.Email = "me@mine.com",
WHERE  (((
            dbo_Master_Accounts.Master_ID
         ) = "000055"
```

But I get a syntax error that I can't see. Tried running with only first and last two line of code and get the same error.

Thanks in advance

jpl

Comment: comma before `where`. Three `(` in your where and only one `)`

Comment: And you're using `"` instead of `'` but that works if you have configured odbc properly

Comment: And you really shouldn't be trusting user input, opens yourself to an injection attack. Use parameters.

Comment: How do I mark this as closed?

Answer (score 0):

Start by trying this to see if it works (removed comma before where, and fixed the parenthesis) and then use parameters to do it right, because this way you're open to SQL injection attacks

```
Dim upDateStr As String
upDateStr = "UPDATE dbo_Master_Accounts SET dbo_Master_Accounts.FirstName = '" & Me.disFirstName & "', "
upDateStr = upDateStr + "dbo_Master_Accounts.LastName = '" & Me.disLastName & "', "
upDateStr = upDateStr + "dbo_Master_Accounts.Address_Line_1 = '" & Me.disAddr1 & "', "
upDateStr = upDateStr + "dbo_Master_Accounts.City = '" & Me.disCity & "', "
upDateStr = upDateStr + "dbo_Master_Accounts.State = '" & Me.disState & "', "
upDateStr = upDateStr + "dbo_Master_Accounts.PostalCode = '" & Me.disPostalCode & "', "
upDateStr = upDateStr + "dbo_Master_Accounts.Phone_Number_1 = '" & Me.disHomePhone & "', "
upDateStr = upDateStr + "dbo_Master_Accounts.Phone_Number_2 = '" & Me.disCellPhone & "', "
upDateStr = upDateStr + "dbo_Master_Accounts.Gender = '" & Me.disGender &  "', "
upDateStr = upDateStr + "dbo_Master_Accounts.Date_Of_Birth = '" & Me.disDateofBirth & "', "
upDateStr = upDateStr + "dbo_Master_Accounts.Email = '" & Me.disEmailAddress & "' "
upDateStr = upDateStr + "WHERE (dbo_Master_Accounts.Master_ID) = '" & Me.frmoldCardno & "' "
```

Comment: The corrections worked just fine. But I am not sure I understand what you mean by a parameter Query.  I assume you are talking about something more than using brackets [] in the query.  Thanks for the help.